# Not receiving stagenet XMR to cli-wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, stagenet

I created a monero CLI wallet a few weeks ago with the --stagenet option:

`./monero-wallet-cli --stagenet --generate-new-wallet ~/example_stagenet_wallet`

I've now just connected it to the monero stagenet:

`./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address monero-stagenet.exan.tech:38081 --stagenet --wallet-file example_stagenet_wallet`

I attempted to have some stagenet XMR sent to my address by going to [this faucet](https://community.xmr.to/faucet/stagenet/) and entering my address into the box. It said that it sent me 10 XMR with this Tx hash:

6ff1259db667622c8ac59faefed5a6d772af2b2042f1779580deee2cc1e6e5f4

However, over an hour later and with 32 confirmations, it's still is not showing in my wallet, even though it is [showing up in the explorer](https://community.xmr.to/explorer/stagenet/tx/6ff1259db667622c8ac59faefed5a6d772af2b2042f1779580deee2cc1e6e5f4). Whenever I type 'refresh' in the CLI wallet, I'm told `Refresh done, blocks received: 0`, suggesting it's not properly connected to the remote stagenet daemon at *monero-stagenet.exan.tech:38081*; however, when I start the wallet it does say `Warning: using an untrusted daemon at monero-stagenet.exan.tech:38081` so it at least *thinks* it's connected to that daemon.

> **Why is the XMR not showing in my wallet?**

I'm totally new to monero and just learning the ropes, and would like to be able to send and receive XMR in this sandbox environment before doing it properly, so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your transaction is apparently in stagenet block at height 565903, but the daemon you are using appears to be stuck back on height 558151 (at time of writing). Thus you need to use a daemon that is up-to-date.

Seeing as you are using the xmr.to explorer and faucet, perhaps use their stagenet daemon too: https://community.xmr.to/nodes.html.

E.g.

```
./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address node.xmr.to:38081 --stagenet \
    --wallet-file example_stagenet_wallet
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `./monerod --stage` to sync the last block before running `./monero-wallet-cli --stage`

It should work, I can see your transaction at my side.

Comment: OP is using a stuck daemon, they do not need to download the whole stagenet blockchain just to verify it worked.